# The real and imaginary parts of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying to evaluate the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ and I was wondering if my solution was correct, as it's quite not nice.

I first wrote out the z's as (x+iy)'s, turning the denominator into $1+x^2 -y^2 -2x +i(2y(1+x))$. Then I multiplied the expression by the complex conjugate of the denominator and did a lot of simplification to turn the expression into $\frac{x^3-2x^2+x+xy^2+2xy+i(-y^3+y-yx^2-2yx-2x^2)}{x^4+y^4-4x^3+2y^2+6x^2-4x+12y^2+2y^2x^2+1}$ . Obviously here you can just split the fraction to obtain the real and imaginary parts. It just seems quite heavy, and I was wondering if my process wasn't the best for this type of problem. Thank you!

Comment: Try substituting $w=1-z$

Comment: Write , $1-z=r( \cos(A)+i\sin (A))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler method: Write $1-z=re^{i\theta}$. You get $\frac {1-re^{i\theta}} {r^{2}e^{2i\theta}}$. Split this into two terms and you will get the answer easily. [$\frac 1 {r^{2}}e^{-2i\theta}-\frac 1 re^{-i\theta}$ has real part $\frac 1 {r^{2}} \cos (2 \theta)-\frac  1 r \cos \theta$ and imaginary part $-\frac 1 {r^{2}} \sin (2 \theta)+\frac  1 r \sin \theta$. Use the identities $\cos (2\theta)=2\cos^{2}\theta -1$ and $\sin (2 \theta)=2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$].

Comment: I've been trying to split this into two terms without working too hard for it while taking the imaginary constant out of the denominator in the process, or fiddling around with things like that, and I'm not seeing any readily apparent ways to succeed. Do you have another little push in the right direction?

Comment: I have added some details.  @J.Ross

Answer (score 1):

By $w=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$, for the real part we have

$$2\Re(w)=w+\bar w=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{\bar z}{(1-\bar z)^2}=\frac{z(1-\bar z)^2+\bar z(1-z)^2}{(1-2\Re(z)+|z|^2)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{2\Re (z)-4|z|^2+2\Re(z)|z|^2}{\left(1-2\Re(z)+|z|^2\right)^2} \implies \Re \left(\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\right) =\frac{x-2(x^2+y^2)+x(x^2+y^2)}{\left(1-2x+x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

and similarly for the imaginary part we obtain

$$2i\Im(w)=w-\bar w=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{\bar z}{(1-\bar z)^2}=\frac{z(1-\bar z)^2-\bar z(1-z)^2}{\left(1-2\Re(z)+|z|^2\right)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{2i\Im (z)-2i\Im(z)|z|^2}{\left(1-2\Re(z)+|z|^2\right)^2} \implies \Im \left(\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\right) =\frac{y-y(x^2+y^2)}{\left(1-2x+x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

---

A more effective way

$$\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\frac{(1-\bar z)^2}{(1-\bar z)^2}=\frac{z-2z\bar z+z\bar z^2}{\left(1-z-\bar z+z\bar z\right)^2}=\frac{z-2|z|^2+\bar z|z|^2}{\left(1-2\Re (z)+|z|^2\right)^2}$$

from which the previous result follows.